# How does one estimate the time until ISS enters/leaves darkness with available data

Tags: iss

I'd like know how sites like helloearth.us or satflare.com/iss calculate the time until the ISS enters/leaves darkness (sunrise/sunset).

Comment: You might want to take a gander at [this article](http://www.castor2.ca/03_Mechanics/02_Elements/index.html)

Comment: Calculate the time when the ISS orbit intersects the earth's shadow cone. Exactly what are you looking for? Equations?